# What is the exact meaning of final-field-safe context in JLS

Tags: java, final, jls

Term *final-field-safe context* is used frequently in paragraph 17.5.3 of JLS (subsequent modification of final fields). Although, as could be understood from specification (if I'm wrong here, please correct me)

```
An implementation may provide a way to execute a block of code
in a final-fieldsafe context.
```

the exact behavior is implementation-dependent, there is still no clear definition of term.

Could I suppose, that if we have a final-field freeze *F* (one that occurs at the end of object construction or final-field set by the means of reflection API) and an action *A*, such that *happens-before(F, A)*, then *A* is in *final-field-safe context*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To help understand what [JLS 17.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3) means by a 'final-field safe context', consider the following code

```
public static final AccountType SINGLETON_ACCOUNT_TYPE = new AwesomeAccountType();
```

Before Java 5, Java had a 'feature' where the thread safety of the construction of AwesomeAccountType and its assignment to SINGLETON_ACCOUNT_TYPE was taken by developers to be safe.  Unfortunately the spec was ambiguous and/or did not state the behavior, which lead to different JVM implementations having different behaviors.  The result was that Java was often not thread safe and portable in this scenario.

The reason for this was that the order of the operations involved in constructing of AwesomeAccountType could get reordered at runtime in such a way that the reference to the object could become visible to another thread before the object was fully constructed.  The behavior was non-deterministic, it always worked on single core CPUs and usually worked on intel CPUs but would fall over in a hurry on CPUs with a weaker memory model such as the Dec Alpha.

A 'final-field safe context' then is the region of code that is involved in the assignment to the above final field (SINGLETON_ACCOUNT_TYPE), and it covers all of the constructor for AwesomeAccountType AND the code internal to the JVM for allocating and initializing the memory for the object.

These changes to the Java Memory Model were made under JSR133, the following FAQ is very useful for understanding the context of the changes that were made: [JSR133 FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalRight).

Comment: So, my guess was all wrong. But I still feel confused. In link to JSR133 FAQ you posted, they mentioned "correctly constructed object". Could I speculate that object was constructed within a final-field-safe context, when neither pointer to this object nor pointer to it's final field leaked during construction? Or I am all wrong again?

Comment: Almost, 'correctly constructed object' is referring to a problem where a ref to the object escapes to other code before the object has been fully constructed (or is at risk of that happening).  Google for 'problems with double checked locking on Java'.  Doug Lea wrote some excellent articles that delve into these problems, and formed the basis for JSR 133.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html is one such example.  The wikipedia page on the topic is also worth a read.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Comment: Correctly constructed, and correctly publishing the reference to the constructed object are related themes. And yes, a final field can be used as part of this publishing (after Java 5). However it is not the only way to do it, nor does it guarantee it by itself. For example, a constructor that calls a method that may be overridden on a object that then calls out to another object must not pass the ref stored in 'this' out of the object otherwise it could be publishing an object that is not fully constructed yet.